# Company's Redirect has Disabled the Back Button - How Did They do It?

Tags: header, http-headers, redirect, http-redirect

URL Tree:

1. agooda.com
2. redirect.protectedbrand.com/filter?dh=7233a55e7da91a60edfd9524825192132c0e3023&sid=15055&s=&t=1473478631&b=0&k=0&h=f73b28b793fa56ed45bf336d3ebb58c4
3. agoda.com

Once user enters agooda.com they are sent to an intermediary page that runs some code then redirects them to agoda.com at which point you can no longer press the back button. It seems very clever because they seem to be doing more than just doing a header change.

I currently have a domain I want to exactly this with: send it to a page that runs an analytics script which can log some data such as how many hits the URL is getting, then forward to the correct domain in a streamlined fashion that doesn't allow the user to go back to the intermediary site. It seems that they're executing exactly that above, so it must be possible!

Here's what I'm running currently that doesn't quite work:

1. forwardingwebsite.com runs the following:

```html
<?php
header('Location: http://intermediaryexample.com/');
exit;
?>
```

2. intermediaryexample.com Runs:

```html
<script>
  // Google Analytics
</script>

<?php
$url='http://example.com/';
   echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';

?>
```

3. example.com

User can still go back to intermediaryexample.com, unlike in the functional demonstration at the beginning. What are they doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

What they have done here is a lot of redirects one after another.

I count 6 redirects so the correct list is:

1. http://agooda.com/
2. http://redirect.protectedparking.com/pp?s=15055&d=agooda.com
3. http://redirect.protectedbrand.com/filter?dh=7233a55e7da91a60edfd9524825192132c0e3023&sid=15055&s=&t=1473701394&b=0&k=0&h=2b01bb223467889c04c76c6272aacb76
4. http://redirect.protectedbrand.com/?b=0&dh=7233a55e7da91a60edfd9524825192132c0e3023&h=2b01bb223467889c04c76c6272aacb76&k=0&s=&r=&t=1473701394&sid=15055
5. http://www.awin1.com/cread.php?awinmid=4275&awinaffid=135363&clickref=g67hjnyucf1kc8tmjp6oo25nd&p=
6. http://www.zenaps.com/rclick.php?mid=4275&c_len=2592000&c_ts=1473701405&c_cnt=135363%7C0%7C%7C1473701405%7Cg67hjnyucf1kc8tmjp6oo25nd%7Caw%7C0&ir=kxpntasj&pr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.agoda.com%2Fpartners%2Fpartnersearch.aspx%3F%26CID%3D1497421%26tag%3D135363&bId=tr14_57d6d0eb91f187.61747974&cookie=1&c_d=zenaps.com
7. https://www.agoda.com/partners/partnersearch.aspx?&CID=1497421&tag=135363

The one of interest to you is number 3.  Instead of doing a HTTP `Location:` it uses javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
if(top.location === location) {
    top.location = '/?b=0&amp;dh=7233a55e7da91a60edfd9524825192132c0e3023&amp;h=2b01bb223467889c04c76c6272aacb76&amp;k=0&amp;s=&amp;r=&amp;t=1473701394&amp;sid=15055';
} else {
    window.location = '/?b=0&amp;dh=7233a55e7da91a60edfd9524825192132c0e3023&amp;h=2b01bb223467889c04c76c6272aacb76&amp;k=0&amp;s=&amp;r=&amp;t=1473701394&amp;sid=15055&framed=1';
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

If you turn off Javascript and goto agooda.com it will all stop at redirect 3 where you can see the source.

So that's what they are doing.  Here how you recreate it:

**a.php**:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
header("Location: http://localhost/b.php");
?>
```

**b.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
top.location = '/c.php';
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

**c.php**:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
?>
Last page.
```

If you want to watch this play out for real you can use the Firefox add-on "Tamper Data" (http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/) and watch it bounce around.